# Proving that $-a=(-1)\cdot a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

As the title reveals, I want to prove (based on the axioms of field) that
$$-a=(-1)\cdot a$$
I've been trying for a while now, but couldn't think of a way to do it and it got me thinking that maybe its does not require a proof, but it doesn't feel right.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the full strength of the field axioms (in particular you don't need division). Just the ring axioms will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Both are inverses of $\rm\,a\,$ so they are equal by [uniqueness of inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033516/242), i.e.

$$\rm \begin{array}{}\rm a'+a\ =\, 0\\ 
      \rm \, a+a'' =\,\! 0\end{array}\quad\Rightarrow\quad a'\, =\ a' + (a + a'')\ =\ (a' + a) + a'' =\, a''\qquad$$
Using that, $ $ it suffices to prove that $\rm\ (-1)\,a + a = 0,\ $ i.e. $\rm\,(-1)\,a\,$ is an inverse of $\rm\,a.$ This follows easily by the ring axioms (hint: scale $\rm\, -1\, +\, 1\, =\, 0\,$ by $\rm\,a)$.

It is useful to abstract out the lemma on uniqueness of inverses since it is ubiquitous in algebra.

Also, as I [often emphasize,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities) uniqueness theorems provide powerful tools for proving equalities.

Answer (score 12):

$$a+(-1)a=(1)a+(-1)a=(1+(-1))a=0\cdot a=0$$Hence by definition we have that $-a=(-1)a$

Added: We also want to show that the additive inverse of $a$ has no ambiguities, i.e., if $x$ and $y$ are the additive inverses of $a$ then $x=y$ and hence we can just denote this element by $-a$. Proof: $$x=x+0=x+(a+y)=(x+a)+y=0+y=y$$

Comment: You have to remember $-a$ is by definition the element you add to $a$ to obtain zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have $$a+(-1)a=(1)a+(-1)a=(1+(-1))a=0a=0$$

To prove that $0a=0$ note that $0a=(0+0)a=0a+0a$ add $-0a$ in both sides

$0=0a+(-0a)=0a+0a+(-0a)=0a$.